# Solving subset sum via the LLL algorithm

Tags: knapsack

I wrote code that solves the subset sum problem via the LLL algorithm, as given in chapter three of the Handbook of Applied Cryptography https://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/

I ran the code on ten random sets, each with positive integers from one to $2^n$, each with a random subset adding up to a target integer. The code found the solution ten out of ten times when $n=10$.

However when I ran the code on ten random sets, each with positive integers from one to $4^n$, each with a random subset adding up to a target integer, the code found the solution only one time out of ten times when $n=10$.

My question is shouldn’t it be the other way around, since the sets with positive integers from one to $4^n$ have a lower density than those with positive integers from one to $2^n$ and the algorithm is supposed to have a higher probability of finding a solution for lower density instances?

What might explain this output?

Answer (score 4):

Caveat: I'm not an expert on these types of attacks.

If a subset-sum instance is of the form $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i x_i = t$, i.e. $n$ is the *length* of the sum, then  density is defined to be $n / \max_i\log a_i$.
It follows that

1. the density of your first subset-sum is $\approx 10/n$
2. the density of your second subset-sum is $\approx 5/n$.

This is lower density (as you claim).
That being said, *both* are actually higher density than is typically required for LLL to solve things. [These notes of Peikert](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/%7Ecpeikert/lic13/lec05.pdf) state that density $2/n$ is typically the threshold for things to start working.

So based on the theory I believe neither should (*guaranteed to*) work with high probability, and instead the threshold for things to work well should be somewhere around $2^{5n}\approx 32^n$ (for your parameterization of things).

Comment: Actually the results I got were only for $n=10$. When I went higher, the results got worse.

Comment: @CraigFeinstein, I guess it might be an implementation problem possibly then? Just a blind guess.

Comment: It could be. I am going to go over things again today.

Comment: Note that there is no theory guaranteeing that the LLL must find solutions with high probability for low density instances. It is only claimed from experiments that it does happen to find solutions in the 1985 paper by Odlyzko and Lagarias. I still have not been able to replicate these but perhaps they were using a different implementation of the algorithm? I do not know.

Comment: Yes there is, see the notes I have linked. LLL (provably) can be used to find a short vector within a factor $2^{n/2}\lambda_1(L)$. With high probability (for appropriate parameters) there is a single such vector, corresponding to the knapsack solution.

Comment: @mark You are correct. I should have qualified that I was only talking about the papers by Odlyzko and Lagarias in which the density does not depend on n. I am only interested in these types of problems.

Comment: I am now wondering whether the problem was that I tested my program for too small a number of n. The result in the Odlyzko Lagarias paper is asymptotic and they tested it on larger n.